# Strange problem using conditional rendering of component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have a simple React component that takes in a single prop, if this prop is 0 show one component otherwise show another.
On page load it equals 0 so the first component loads, once my Redux store is updated from localstorage this value in the parent component updates its local state passing down the new prop to my component.
What happens is rather than switching to render my other component it puts the second component inside of the first... I have never seen this behaviour before and cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I have tried all sorts, switching between stateless and functional components, I have tried using componentWillReceiveProps to receive the updated prop and setState based on this and have my conditional logic based on state. All with the same results.

```
const ComponentThatGetsUpdated = (props) => (
    props.PropThatGetsUpdated === 0 ? <ComponentOne /> : <ComponentTwo />
);
```

I expect on page load the output to be the contents of

```
<div>contents of component one</div>
```

then once my redux store has updated the new props are passed down the output should now be the contents of component two

```
<div>contents of component two</div>
```

The actual output once props have been updated is

```
<ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo></ComponentTwo>
<ComponentOne />
```

FYI the parent component of ComponentThatGetsUpdated looks like the below:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {PropToPassDown: 0}
        this.sub = this.sub.bind(this);
        const sub = store.subscribe(this.sub);
    }
    sub() {
        //when my redux store is updated this function runs and sets PropToPassDown to the new value, for this example it sets PropToPassDown in local state to 1
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ComponentThatGetsUpdated PropToPassDown={this.state.PropToPassDown} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Show use where are you calling `ComponentThatGetsUpdated` component, because it looks that you're wrapping it with `div.one`

Comment: Please add more code so we can help. Where/how are you using `ComponentThatGetsUpdated`?

Comment: You need to show us where are you calling `ComponentThatGetsUpdated` component. We already had your output.

Comment: I have added the parent component, there is nothing fancy going on. It is just a component that updates a value and passes it down to the child

Comment: If `<ComponentOne /><ComponentTwo/><ComponentOne />` is the output when the value change, what is the output when the `PropThatGetsUpdated ` is 0?

Comment: On page load PropThatGetsUpdated is 0, and the output is to be expected, just the contents of the first component. The problem is only when the props get updated.